How to reused openapi schema in api platform
I don’t find how to reusing schema for open api when I used the Model\Operation class in openapi attribute.
For example below (in resource class in php with native attributes):
new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/books',
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                responses: [
                    '200' => [
                        'description' => 'Get a collection of Book resources',
                        'content' => [
                            'application/ld+json' => [
                                'schema' => [
                                    'type' => 'object',
                                    'properties' => [
                                        '@context' => ['type' => 'string'],
                                        '@id' => ['type' => 'string'],
                                        '@type' => ['type' => 'integer'],
                                        'hydra:totalItem' => ['type' => 'integer'],
                                        'hydra:member' => [
                                            'type' => 'array',
                                            'items' => [
                                                'type' => 'object',
                                                'properties' => [
                                                    'id' => ['type' => 'string'],
                                                    'title' => ['type' => 'string'],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                summary: 'Retrieve a collection of Book resources',
                description: 'Retrieve a collection of Book resources'
            ),
        ),

If I need this schema in another resource, how do I ?
Thanks.
I try to add schemas index like openapi documentation https://learn.openapis.org/specification/components.html but it not works.
PS: I can't use #[ApiProperty(openapiContext)] because it already used for Post and Get class in the same resource.
